# Project individual elements on the surface of other objects

Tags: modeling, objects

When I try to project the blue item onto the shoe from top view by pressing <kbd>G</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and Mouse-click, the blue item gets distorted. Any idea why and how to fix it? I have tried turning snap on and off but didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*ShrinkWrap* modifier seems to be working quite well on my end.
[image]

You geometry is quite uneven though, some triangles, very long and narrow faces with and slightly twisted topology may be screwing up your shape. Improving that may yield better results.